# Why would a teen TV show need an FBI warning inside the Young Justice universe?

Tags: realism, young-justice

In *Young Justice S01E21*, when Garfield plays the pilot episode of his mother's TV show Hello Megan, a statutory warning appears:

[image]
[image]

It is not clear enough to read the whole text, but why would a teen show inside the Young Justice universe have an FBI warning before the show? How realistic is it? Or is it based on something from the real world?

Comment: @Walt ooops, didn't expected that simple answer. Should I take this answer down then or you answering it.

Comment: Three answer already

Comment: Only 2. Someone else gave the same as mine but with a good image, so I delete mine and upvote his. :)

Comment: @Longspeak they were all close, so could have kept yours, anyways whatever you feel right :)

Comment: @AnkitSharma Oh I wasn't complaining or anything. I know they were close. But the other was better. If I had the better answer, it'd still be there. :p

Comment: @Longspeak  fair enough, be fast next time ;)

Comment: I'd still delete my own half-assed answer in favor of someone else's better answer. :D

Comment: That's what "statutory warning" means - must be included by statute.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When you buy DVD (or VHS, or BluRay, or LaserDisc, or BetaMax, or VCD) in the United States, they come with an anti-piracy warning. You aren't supposed to copy or redistribute the product you purchased.

[image]
[image]

Comment: did you get permission to use those graphics? ;-)

Comment: Ironically you don't see these warnings if you pirate the movie

Answer (score 9):

In the United States, it is extremely common for home video releases (laserdisc, videotape, DVD, Blu-ray, etc.) to include an [anti-piracy warning](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/thr-esq/fbi-anti-piracy-warnings-over-time-pictures-322495) before the main feature.

Comment: [This image](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8163/7165455234_252e05d633.jpg) from your link even matches the most, anyways nice answer +1